# SSL settings spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I have some questions about ssl in spring boot.
I have files certifications and private key with extension .crt and .key. how can I get from them right format for settings in spring boot like this

```
    server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
    server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
    server.ssl.key-store-password=password 
    server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a certificate file and private key to PKCS#12(.p12) format, use the below command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

Please go through the below links for your reference on dealing with https in spring boot.

1. [Enable HTTPS in Spring Boot](https://snmaddula.bitbucket.io/enable-https-in-spring-boot-app/)
2. [Configure HTTP to HTTPS Redirection in Spring Boot](https://snmaddula.bitbucket.io/configure-https-redirect-connector-spring-boot/)

Answer (score 2):

I found solution. I got keystore use this comand:

```
    openssl pkcs12 -export -in <mycert.crt> -inkey <mykey.key> -out keystore.p12 -name <alias>
```

And added keystore into application.properies

```
    #ssl
    server.port=8443
    server.ssl.enabled=true
    server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
    **server.ssl.key-store=keystore/keystore.p12**
    server.ssl.key-store-password=password
    server.ssl.key-alias=alias
```

It is correct config. When I use classpath:keystore.p12 it did not work. Maybe it cause that I work with spring boot 2. Then I created external folder and put inside keystore. Now it is working.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your solution? did you create a folder under ressources? why did you ** that line in the config? That issue is driving me mad

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative:** if you don't have (or don't like?) OpenSSL, https://keystore-explorer.org/ (unlike keytool) can read privatekey+certs into any type of Java keystore (PKCS12, JCEKS, JKS, and more, but PKCS12 is usually best) with the "Import Key Pair" icon or menu item.

Answer (score 0):

you can set certifications and private key with extension .crt and .key. as is in SpringBoot 3.1+

```
server.port=443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.certificate=file:/certs/tls.crt
server.ssl.certificate-private-key=file:/certs/tls.key
```