# Spring boot after https: The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, ssl, https

I read almost all resources, tried everything I could get my hands on which would seem to be duplicate on this website but have no luck to make it work.

The following works when running in IntelliJ on a windows machine but failed when running as a JAR compiled with Maven on Ubuntu. It would seem to me as if it cannot find the file.

8443 is free, there are no firewall.
I tried the long path as well but not working (server.ssl.keystore=file:/home/@@@/Documents/keystoref.p12 )

```
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat         
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12         
server.ssl.key-store-password=@@@         
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystoref.p12         
server.port=8443         
server.ssl.enabled=true


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8443 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8443, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I am also unsure what private key to use. Should I use the private key which helps to generate the CSR which I had to convert into p12

[Generating CSR](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9422/14/generating-a-csr-on-tomcat-using-a-keytool/)

Or should I use the p12 generated from the mix of my private key and the 'certificate.crt' I received in email as per this previous answer. I would think the private key is linked to the certificate anyway so that should make no difference?

```
    openssl pkcs12 -export -in <mycert.crt> -inkey <mykey.key> -out keystore.p12 -name <alias>
```

[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228577/ssl-settings-spring-boot)

Comment: the applicaion,properties config with the .p12 file works fine actually with a new demo project. When I am adding JPA + Postgres dependency it would seem to break the current configuration

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you tried

`server.ssl.keystore=file:/home/@@@/Documents/keystoref.p12`

Did you try using:

`server.ssl.key-store=file:/home/@@@/Documents/keystoref.p12` ?

Comment: yes that was a typo in the question formatting. thanks nevertheless

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to locate the issue with this problem. I started a fresh project and built on it and never encountered this issue again, so on my end this issue is being closed. Also the first key used to generate the CSR works just fine.

**Update**
The issue came from the spring version on pom.xml for whatever reason, once changed from

```
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>    
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>    
 <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
```

to version 2.3.1.RELEASE it worked fine.